# Different results when using and not using commands.js or it blocks

Tags: automation, cypress, pageobjects

I'm using Cypress.io for front-end automation.

When I type all the commands directly into the spec, all within one it block, the test passes.

But if I put the commands into commands.js, within several Cypress.Commands.add blocks, or in individual it blocks within the spec, the test fails.

I don't know why. Below is my commands.js file

```
Cypress.Commands.add ("modals", {prevSubject: false}, () => {
    cy.get('#continueInBrowserBtn').should('be.visible').click()
    cy.get('#cpp-agree-btn').should('be.visible').click()
})

Cypress.Commands.add ("loginGuest", {prevSubject: false}, () => {
    cy.get('#input_email-info').should('be.visible').type('eric+test@centraldesktop.com')
    cy.get('#email-continue-btn').should('be.visible').click()
    cy.get('pgi-label-input.guest-input.first-name.web-input-area.ng-untouched.ng-pristine').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('pgi-label-input.guest-input.first-name.web-input-area.ng-untouched.ng-pristine > div > input').type('Eric')
    cy.get('pgi-label-input.guest-input.last-name.web-input-area.ng-untouched.ng-pristine > div > input').type('Test')
    cy.get('div.guest-continue-button.continue-button > pgi-text-button > button').click()
    cy.get('pgi-text-button.ng-tns-c8-0.ng-star-inserted > button > span').should('be.visible').click()
    cy.wait(3000)
})

Cypress.Commands.add ("loginHost", {prevSubject: false}, () => {
    cy.log('Enter Email')
    cy.get('#input_email-info').should('be.visible').type('6597076')
    cy.get('.pgi-button-wrapper').should('be.visible').click()

    cy.log('Enter Password')
    cy.get('#input_password-info').should('be.visible').type('r44XkP33')

    cy.log('Click Sign in')
    cy.get('#password-signin-btn > button > span').should('be.visible').click()
})

Cypress.Commands.add ("logout", {prevSubject: false}, () => {
    cy.get('bottom-container-right > div > div > div').should('be.visible').click()
    cy.get('pgi-text-button.yes-button > button > span').should('be.visible').click()
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.get('feedback-panel > pgi-panel > h2').should('be.visible')
})
```

Comment: What's the failure looks like? Is there any error message? Also, can you provide a more narrow code example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score -1):

After reading the best practices section of Cypress Docs, I realized my way is incorrect